# Hard disk not showing instead booting memory card storage was showing

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a hp laptop with 1TB storage , 8gb RAM .

I want to install Ubuntu alongside windows10 (original)
I have a bootable memory card (32gb)
I booted it using Rufus
I completely formated the memory card and then only i made it as bootable
I booted the memory card with gbt option

I have tried to boot it many times using various steps, but all the time I have problem that the partition table was remaining empty while I tried to install the Ubuntu after live Ubuntu .

But I referred problems and solutions in askubuntu , finally i got the partition that showing the disk space in the booting memory card , but still the partition table not showing my hard disk .

For Ubuntu i already have unallocated space (413gb) in Windows.

But since the partition table not showing these 413gb.

What I want to do to install the Ubuntu alongside windows10(original)

Comment: What information i want to say sir .

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1335474/edit) to show your 1TB HDD in Windows Disk Manager and in GParted.

Comment: Drives not visible in a Ubuntu live session (or installed OS) almost always have to do with unsupported modes like "RAID" or "Intel RST". If you have one of those you need to change to "AHCI" but before you do that make sure to install AHCI support in Windows.